# how to find the most optimal path for this problem?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

There are N islands and there is one pirate. The pirate can start out from any one of the n islands and has the option of either staying on the same island for the next day or moving to a different island.

All the islands are connected to each other by routes. Each evening of the day the pirate steals some gold on the island he is in. The amount of gold the pirate steals depends on the day and the island the pirate is on, and this is given by S[n_i][m_j], where m represents a day of out M days and n represents an island out of N islands.

The pirate has only m number of days to explore whichever islands he wants and steal.

The pirate also looses some percentage of his gold **first before** getting the day's steal of gold. The percentage the pirate looses depends on the current (i) then the previous island (j) he was in, and is given by L[i][j], where 0 <= L[I][j] <= 100. There is no limitation on the number of times the pirate can visit an island i.

I need an O(N^2*M) algorithm to calculate the maximum gold that the pirate can steal and also provides the path the pirate takes.

What I tried to do:

I tried to maximise the steal and minimise the gold lost

For day one, choose the island with the most steal

For the rest of the days: calculate best combination of loss and steal by: (net total = current total gold - loss + gain).

I am not sure if this is the way to go about it. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome!  I'm formulating an answer, but I wanted to let you know that I modified your question to change the capitalization of M and N in a few places.  I think you intended M and N to be the sizes of the days and islands (respectively), while m and n were indexes into those arrays.  Please let me know if I misinterpreted that.  My answer will be predicated on my interpretation being sane

Comment: You will have to use dynic programming to solve this question, a simple greedy algorithm might not consider a different path where the steal is a bit lower, but the lose is much mich lower on a **future** choice

Comment: @CortAmmon yes that is correct, thank you for fixing it!

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  Can you credit the original source?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401650/how-to-find-the-most-optimal-path-for-this-problem.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is the required bound: $O(N^2\cdot m)$  This is a nice cushy bound, which is good news for us.  The $N^2$ bit tells me that we can visit all pairs of islands (leaving one of $N$ islands and arriving at one of the $N-1$ other islands).  And the $M$ bit tells me that that process of visiting all of the islands can be done once for every day on the journey.  So if you can come up with a process that visits each pair of islands once on each leg of the journey, you'll meet the bounds needed.

The second thing I notice is that there's no connectivity graph to worry about.  Every island appears to be connected to every other island.  This is useful because it means you don't really need to find a "path," in the graph theory sense, but rather a "sequence" of islands to visit.  Pathfinding is much harder, so I'm happy not to have to do it!

Thinking from a pareto point of view, given any two paths that end on the same island, there is never a reason to consider the one that earns less gold.  So we can use this as a filter to cut down the number of paths considered.  While I might want to accept less gold in order to end up on a more favorable island, I will never accept less gold *and* end up at the same island.

Algorithm:

- Start on the first day.  Initialize an array of $M$ "best path ending in island $m$ after day 0".  This is trivial: the only way to end up on an island is to visit it on day 0 is to visit it, so we initialize our "best path ending in island $m$" to $S[0][m]$, and record the 1-step path.
- Iterate until we reach the last day

  - Determine the best path to each island on day $j$
  - For each island $m$, compute the best path ending in island $m$ after $j$ days.  This can be computed in $(N^2)$ time simply by looking at the best path to every island in the previous steps, and computing the paths to every island on this step from there.  The best path to each island is simply the maximum gold-earning path to that island from any of the previous islands.

This takes $M$ iterations.  Each iteration involves creating $N$ new "best path to island $i$".  Each best path requires looking at $N$ possible previous paths, one ending on each island.